# How to search for an ordered subset of array in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, search

Given this, three MongoDB objects

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "array" : [ "a", "b", "c" ]
}
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "array" : [ "a", "b", "c" ]
}
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "array" : [ "x", "a", "b", "c" ]
}
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "array" : [ "x", "b", "c", "a" ]
}
```

I would like to search in two different ways.

First I like to find all object where array starts with ["a", "b"] in that order, which should be objects 1,2 but not 3 and 4.

And I would like to search for all objects where array contains ["a", "b"] in that order, which should be 1,2,3 and not 4.

Any ideas how I search for a subset of an array in that order, and / or starting at the beginning of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for an ordered subset, you can try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        "$eq": [
          {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$array",
              "as": "item",
              "cond": {
                "$in": [
                  "$$item",
                  [
                    "a",
                    "b"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          [
            "a",
            "b"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

In this query, we first filter the array to only contain the elements present in the subset, and then we compare the arrays, to see if they are in order or not.

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vhdTjgNHlJA)

To check for an ordered array at the beginning, slice the array and then compare, it like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        "$eq": [
          {
            "$slice": [
              "$array",
              2
            ]
          },
          [
            "a",
            "b"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RnriaVEOk3K)

Comment: I did not think about the aggregation pipeline. Thank you very much! :)